# Backing up cpanel files in home dir. What issues may arise?

Tags: linux, backup, web-server, rsync

I'm doing an rsync backup of my home directory on my web host.  My webhost uses cpanel and I noticed that there are some cpanel directories in my home directory that I'm backing up.  Is this going to cause issues if I ever do a restore?  Will it revert my cpanel changes to that date as well?  or will it just cause more issues than I want to deal with?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Just exclude the .cpanel directories with rsync and you should be fine.